# Asking good question about finding a broker allowing wallet to wallet transfer

Tags: support

I am googling and googling but can't identify the easiest/securiest way to buy Ethereum and transfer it to 3rd party wallet.

The local broker of my choice came out not to support this operation so obviously they do have just their own wallet.

It feels like asking "Where to find such a broker to support wallet to wallet operations" might get me negative score so please help. Maybe this has been asked already many times but I can't find.

Comment: It is not a good question for the site. It depends on several factors, place of residency, local regulations, knowledge about crypto and security measures, etc. Also exchanges change over time, any list would get obsolete quite quickly.

I'd recommend to look for a crypto related group in your city or country and ask them what are the recommended options. You could try other social networks like twitter, reddit, linkedin, etc.

Comment: thx - will try this way. Indeed I thought maybe there are some prominent review portals featuring such lists/comparing matrices like you find this for any other topic

Comment: Upvoted Ismael's comment but in case helpful, there's a country list at https://ethereum.org/en/get-eth/  and some meetups at https://ethereum.org/en/community/events/  Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!